# How to set default values in dropdown list when the page is loaded- in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created two dropdown lists in aspx page as

```
                  <div class="row-form">
                <div class="span3">
                    Line of Authority&nbsp;<span class="RequiredField">* </span>:
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="drpLineOfAuthority" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="drpJurisdiction_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                <!-- <tpLineOfAuthority:ctLineOfAuthority ID ="chkLineOfAuthority" runat="server" /> -->
                </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>

              <div  class="row-form">
                <div class="span3">
                    State&nbsp;<span class="RequiredField">* </span>:
                </div>

                <div class="span3">
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="drpJurisdiction" AutoPostBack="true"        onselectedindexchanged="drpJurisdiction_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
             </div>
```

In aspx.cs file as

```
                protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                 if (!IsPostBack)
                 {
                 if (urlAction != URLAction.update)
                 {
                  FillDropDown();
                 }
                 }
             }

       private void FillDropDown()
       {
        JurisdictionBL jbl;
        jbl = new JurisdictionBL(0);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        jbl.FetchAll(ds);
        ...
        ...
         if (urlAction != URLAction.update)
        {
            drpJurisdiction.SelectedValue = "--Please select any state--";
            drpLineOfAuthority.SelectedValue = "--Please select LOA--";
        }
    }
```

Note that FillDropDown() function is filling dropdown list items with values, these values are retrieved from database.
Now the issue is the above code is not setting default values to the dropdown lists!!!
Please help me!!!

Comment: `--Please select any state--` & `--Please select LOA--` are your value for dropdown option? These should be text! Show the data which is binding your dropdown.

Comment: Yes sir it should be the default value

Comment: use drpJurisdiction.SelectedIndex = 0

Comment: @Nida - I mean this will be displayed to the user right? Whats the corresponding `value` for these options? Show your data.

Comment: It contains lot of data, it is not possible to show data...

Comment: @Nida - I am not asking you to show complete data, what is the corresponding value of `Please select any state`? You must be binding by assigning a `Text` & `Value` to your dropdown right?

Comment: try like this drpJurisdiction.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Please select any state--", "0"));

Comment: @ArunPrasanth: Your code is perfectly working ... Thanks

Comment: It's very glad to here its working fine for you , i will add that as an answer

Comment: Actually I want that when the page is loaded, these drop down lists should show default values like --please select ----- at first time... That was my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  like this, it will work

```
drpJurisdiction.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Please select any state--", "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring `AppendDataBoundItems` property.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpJurisdiction" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Please select any state--" Value="" />   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Make sure the `AppendDataBoundItems` is set to true or else it will get cleared when you bind data in code behind.

Alternately,

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpJurisdiction" ondatabound="OndrpJurisdictionDataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
protected void OndrpJurisdictionDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drpJurisdiction.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Please select any state--", ""));
}
```

Comment: Why you want to change OPs data source and hard code default in code?

Comment: @Nida, This might be because of the AutoPostBack="true". However, why don't you try the alternate approach, which was given on the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the list from the database does not include the strings "--Please select any state--" and "--Please select LOA--", Please make sure that you have the default values in the source datatable.

For example if datatable DT is having the retrived values from the database you can add the default values as a new row at runtime

```
    DataRow DR = DT.NewRow();
    DR[0] = "--Please select LOA--";
    DT.Rows.InsertAt(DR, 0);
```

Comment: How you came to know that"the list from the database does not include the strings"?

Comment: The values that can be set in a DropDownList or ComboBox cannot be anything other that the list they are initilized with.